# Angular JS add row to ng-repeat table with different controls than other rows

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table populated with json data and an ng-repeat, as in

[image]

I need to add rows to the top with a button, as in the screenshot, but the added row(s) has to have *editable* cells where I have blank rows.  The data in the existing rows cannot be editable.

I am adding the row with an ng-click handler on the "add" button on the page:

```
    $scope.addRow = function () {
       $scope.hsCodes.unshift({});
    };
```

This works, but of course adds a row just like the others, with empty TDs.

How can I add input (text) controls only to the added row(s)?

Comment: Think of using Angular-xeditable. It's a nice library for inline editing: https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/ . You can have a look at 'Editable row' example. If you'd like to make it manually, you can think of providing additional field for each record (e.g. `isEditable`). In the view you can use `ng-if` to show row with textboxes if `isEditable` is `true` or just text if it's `false`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I know about that and use it sometimes.  For this product, they want to use plain tables.  Good idea about the extra flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to have a demo to more accurately answer, but generally what I would do is:

1. Add a boolean property to the row object such as isEditable.
2. Set a template for the cell using ng-if="row.isEditable"

If the row.isEditable property is not there, that would be false, so you don't have to worry about adding it if you are dealing with remote data.